# How custom element can have multiple <tr> components

Tags: html-table, aurelia

I want create a one `<table>` where multiple custom elements can have multiple `<tr>` components.
I tried using `containerless`, but element get rendered outside of `<table>`.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <order-line repeat.for="line of lines" line.to-view="line" containerless></order-line>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And custom element looks like

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>${line.position}</td>
    <td>${line.name}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr if.to-view="detailsVisible">
    <td colspan="2">${line.complicatedDescription}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

How I can get a table row with details as another `<tr>` element within one aurelia CustomElement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the html spec. A `<table>` element cannot contain elements other than `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, etc.

You can use `as-element` to overcome this limitation:

```html
<tr as-element="order-line" repeat.for="line of lines" line.to-view="line" containerless></tr>
```

This tells the template compiler that this `<tr>` is in fact an `order-line` custom element and to process it as such. At the same time, it "fools" the browser into thinking that this is just an ordinary `<tr>`

Comment: As Fred correctly stated, I made a test project with this, and the main issue is solved. You can check it out at https://codesandbox.io/embed/tables-tr-cwmdr.

Answer (score 1):

`<table>` can contain multiple `<tbody>` elements, this will allow to wrap multiple `<tr>` elements inside custom element with `<tbody>`.

```
/* custom element */
<template>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>${line.position}</td>
      <td>${line.name}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr if.to-view="detailsVisible">
      <td colspan="2">${line.complicatedDescription}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

Use as custom element inside

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <order-line repeat.for="line of lines" line.to-view="line"></order-line>
</table>
```